# PSQLException index out of bound

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I can't figure out why my PreparedStatement is throwing an error.

Here is my function:

```
public boolean updateMail(int id, String new_mail, boolean showMail) {
    String login = "";
    String toUpdate = "";
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        req = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT login FROM compte WHERE id = ?");
        req.setInt(1, id); 
        ResultSet rs = req.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) login = rs.getString(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!getDestinataire(login).equals(new_mail))
        toUpdate = ", new_mail=?";
    String reqq = "UPDATE compte SET show_mail=?" + toUpdate + " WHERE id=?";
    System.out.println("Dest : " + getDestinataire(login) + "\nnew_mail : " + new_mail + "\ntoUpdate : " + toUpdate
            + "\nreqq : " + reqq);
    try {
        req = cnx.prepareStatement(reqq);
        req.setBoolean(1, showMail);
        if (!getDestinataire(login).equals(new_mail)) {
            req.setString(2, new_mail);
        }
        req.setInt(2 + (getDestinataire(login).equals(new_mail) ? 0 : 1), id);
        req.executeUpdate();
        ret = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The `getDestinataire()` method is working well. The trace I'm printing out looks like this:

> Dest : example@example.com new_mail : example2@example2.com toUpdate : ,
>   new_mail=? reqq : UPDATE compte SET show_mail=?, new_mail=? WHERE id=?

So basically I have 3 columns: `show_mail`, `new_mail` and `id`.

But I have an error at `req.setString(2, new_mail);`:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: L'indice de la colonne est hors limite : 2, nombre de colonnes : 1.
```

I tried with and without the `req.close()` because I usually don't use it and it always worked great.

Also, this is the variable definition:

```
private Connection cnx;
private PreparedStatement req;
```

I already wrote a hundred database calls. Is this a stupid mistake that I'm too blind to see or is there a lib bug?

Comment: ALWAYS close a database resource (`Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`) in a `finally` block. It does NOT work great. Also, what happens if you use two different `PreparedStatement` variables, instead of cannibalising the not-closed `req` one?

Comment: You're right ! With another one it works great. So I'll add a finally block to all my try/catch. But the finally isn't a part of the actual try/catch(SQLException), so I have to add a try/catch couple INSIDE the finally ? Also does the finally would be executed if my try have a return statement ? Thanks for your reply !

Comment: `finally` always gets executed, no matter what. Just don't put a `return` statement inside a `finally` block, because then you get strange behaviour. One thing I forgot to mention is that you probably want to use Java 7's try-with-resources, because otherwise, yes, closing a resource can throw a checked exception that you have to handle. It's one of the many problems of JDBC. So something like `try(PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query)){` and so on.